# Using ant design, how can i implement a text area as a search?

Tags: reactjs, search, input, antd

I'm trying to create an search input box using antd, but the input box doesnt seem to allow for autosize (when more than one line of text is input, it doesnt get bigger). I've tried to implement a textArea because that allows for resizing, but this doesnt come witht the search button. How can I implement the textarea for searching?

https://ant.design/components/input/

Comment: [Is this what you are looking for?](https://ant.design/components/input/#components-input-demo-autosize-textarea)